# eclipse neon.2 does not recognize workspace and resets all installed plugins after restart macbook

Tags: eclipse, macos

I have new **MacBook Pro** and **OSX 10.12.1** installed on it.

I have installed **Eclipse Neon.2** on it and everything worked fine. I have installed Subclipse, Jetty and some more plugins on it.

After I restart macbook, Eclipse does not recognize my workspace. I am selecting workspace but this time, the plugins are not available.

I have to install every time after restart.